# How can I create a filter to display all records created by group members in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I want to create a filter for list view, where I want to show all the records created by user group.

We all know [Me] will filter out the records which are craeted by me. i.e. Created by equals to = [Me]

How can I create a filter to display all records created by only the group members.
Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Great question - seems like it ought to be able to do this but agree with Luis, not an OOTB option. Would like to know the answer myself.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do this out of the box.

A way to do this is to use an event receiver on that list, on item inserted / updated with some logic to extract the group from the user and populate a field of that item.

Once you have the column with the group value you can then apply a filter to it normally.

Reader here about event receivers:

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/sp2007dev/pages/event%20receivers.aspx

You want to be looking at using event receivers on the SPListItem object.